# TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/ entries/index.html, entries/entry_list.html

Tags: django

**I need an extra pair of eyes, I just cannot see the mistake, below you can see all the necessary files, I think the error comes from there**
[image: this is the error I am getting]

[image: there you can see the file structure]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Entry
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name='entries/index.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import HomeView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view(), name='blog-home')
]
```

**base urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('entries.urls'))
]
```

**templates settings**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Share the settings for `TEMPLATES`.

Comment: don't you have `{% include "entries/entry_list.html" %}` in your `index` template?

Comment: don't you have {% include "entries/entry_list.html" %} in your index template? nope

Comment: Share the settings for TEMPLATES... just added it ;]

Comment: Good thing you shared your text editor with all the files open. You named your template index.hmtl instead of .html ;) (If it says it doesn't exist, IT DOESN'T EXIST!!! hehe)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the templates dirs in settings.py , change this

```
    'DIRS': [],
```

to this

```
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

in the settings.py file , template settings